# How to add update buttons in rows of a Oracle Apex interactive report?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a report and a form separately rather than creating a "report with form" in my Oracle Apex application. Because of this there are no update buttons that appear on the left of every row in the report like it does when creating "report with form". How can I add these buttons such that I can use same form, which I am currently using just to create new records, to also update records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the report is in Interactive Report type.
Those are the ones which are normally created for report with form.

In which case if you go under the reports attributes the first one is Link,
by default it should be set to Exclude Link column. You should set it to Link to Custom Target, then define the link to go to your page and set the Primary key item.

And on your form page you also need to set an After Header process to fetch the row and fill the page items based on the filled Primary key. Or you can do something custom here, whatever floats your boat.